# Input data from Java to SQL Database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a school project where I have to create a register and login GUI with Netbeans and then link it with a SQL database. I create the database and my login work, but I am struggling with my register maybe someone can help me. This is what I did so far. Sorry for the long code post ,but my mistake could be anywhere here.

```
public class Register extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conn = null;
Statement stat = null;
ResultSet res = null;

public Register() 
{
    initComponents();
}

private Connection connect() {
    // SQLite connection string
    String url = "\"jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDataBase\", \"LouwDataBase\", \"1234\"";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}

public void insert(String Email, String Password, String Name, String Surname, String Address, String Cell)
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Table1Test(Email, Password, Name, Surname, Address, Cell) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try (Connection conn = this.connect();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, Email);
        pstmt.setString(2, Password);
        pstmt.setString(3, Name);
        pstmt.setString(4, Surname);
        pstmt.setString(5, Address);
        pstmt.setString(6, Cell);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jNameLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jRegisterNextButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jNameLbl1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jNameLbl2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jNameLbl3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jNameLbl4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jNameLbl5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jNameLbl6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jNameRegisterField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jAddressRegisterField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jSurnameRegisterField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jCellRegisterField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jEmailRegisterField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jCPasswordRegisterField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    jPasswordRegisterField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    jNameLbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jNameLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jNameLbl.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jNameLbl.setText("Name");
    jNameLbl.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    getContentPane().add(jNameLbl);
    jNameLbl.setBounds(10, 99, 230, 30);

    jRegisterNextButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jRegisterNextButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jRegisterNextButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jRegisterNextButton.setText("Next");
    jRegisterNextButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jRegisterNextButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jRegisterNextButton);
    jRegisterNextButton.setBounds(10, 410, 100, 35);

    jLabel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel2.setText("Register");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
    jLabel2.setBounds(10, 11, 620, 77);

    jNameLbl1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jNameLbl1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jNameLbl1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jNameLbl1.setText("Email");
    jNameLbl1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    getContentPane().add(jNameLbl1);
    jNameLbl1.setBounds(10, 190, 230, 30);

    jNameLbl2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jNameLbl2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jNameLbl2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jNameLbl2.setText("Address");
    jNameLbl2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    getContentPane().add(jNameLbl2);
    jNameLbl2.setBounds(10, 230, 230, 30);

    jNameLbl3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jNameLbl3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jNameLbl3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jNameLbl3.setText("Surname");
    jNameLbl3.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(130, 30));
    jNameLbl3.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(130, 30));
    jNameLbl3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(130, 30));
    getContentPane().add(jNameLbl3);
    jNameLbl3.setBounds(10, 140, 230, 30);

    jNameLbl4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jNameLbl4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jNameLbl4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jNameLbl4.setText("Cell");
    jNameLbl4.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl4.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl4.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    getContentPane().add(jNameLbl4);
    jNameLbl4.setBounds(10, 270, 230, 30);

    jNameLbl5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jNameLbl5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jNameLbl5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jNameLbl5.setText("Password");
    jNameLbl5.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl5.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl5.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    getContentPane().add(jNameLbl5);
    jNameLbl5.setBounds(10, 310, 200, 30);

    jNameLbl6.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jNameLbl6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jNameLbl6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jNameLbl6.setText("Confirm Password");
    jNameLbl6.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl6.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    jNameLbl6.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 30));
    getContentPane().add(jNameLbl6);
    jNameLbl6.setBounds(10, 346, 230, 30);

    jNameRegisterField.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jNameRegisterField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jNameRegisterFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jNameRegisterField);
    jNameRegisterField.setBounds(250, 100, 350, 30);

    jAddressRegisterField.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jAddressRegisterField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jAddressRegisterFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jAddressRegisterField);
    jAddressRegisterField.setBounds(250, 221, 350, 30);

    jSurnameRegisterField.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jSurnameRegisterField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jSurnameRegisterFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jSurnameRegisterField);
    jSurnameRegisterField.setBounds(250, 140, 350, 30);

    jCellRegisterField.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jCellRegisterField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jCellRegisterFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jCellRegisterField);
    jCellRegisterField.setBounds(250, 260, 350, 30);

    jEmailRegisterField.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jEmailRegisterField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jEmailRegisterFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jEmailRegisterField);
    jEmailRegisterField.setBounds(250, 180, 350, 30);

    jCPasswordRegisterField.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jCPasswordRegisterField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jCPasswordRegisterFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jCPasswordRegisterField);
    jCPasswordRegisterField.setBounds(250, 340, 350, 30);

    jPasswordRegisterField.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jPasswordRegisterField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jPasswordRegisterFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jPasswordRegisterField);
    jPasswordRegisterField.setBounds(250, 300, 350, 30);

    jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("D:\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\IT PAT\\PAT Images\\safari_sunset_2512555k1.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("jLabel3");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel3);
    jLabel3.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jNameRegisterFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                  

private void jSurnameRegisterFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                     

private void jPasswordRegisterFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                      

private void jAddressRegisterFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                     

private void jRegisterNextButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    Register Reg = new Register();
    Reg.insert(jEmailRegisterField.getText(), jPasswordRegisterField.getText(), jNameRegisterField.getText(),
            jSurnameRegisterField.getText(), jAddressRegisterField.getText(), jCellRegisterField.getText());
}                                                   

private void jCPasswordRegisterFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                       

private void jCellRegisterFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                  

private void jEmailRegisterFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                   

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {


    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            new Register().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in your URL you should not set your url like a String like you do :

```
String url = "\"jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDataBase\", \"LouwDataBase\", \"1234\"";
```

You have to separate the url, the username and password like this :

```
private Connection connect() {
    // SQLite connection string
    String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDataBase";
    String username = "LouwDataBase"; 
    String password = "1234"; 
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;

}
```